# How to compose this code further using ramda?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ramda.js

I managed to refactor this code to what it's look like now, but I feel that it can be better and cleaner

```
const App = config => createStackNavigator({ /* */ }, config)
const SignIn = config => createStackNavigator({ /* */ }, config)
const SignUp = config => createStackNavigator({ /* */ }, config)

const stackNavigatorConfig = { /* */ }

const stacks = {
  SignUp: SignUp(stackNavigatorConfig),
  SignIn: SignIn(stackNavigatorConfig),
  App: App(stackNavigatorConfig),
  Loading,
}

const switchNavigatorConfig = { /* */ }

const Navigator = compose(
  createAppContainer,
  createAnimatedSwitchNavigator
)(stacks, switchNavigatorConfig)

export default Navigator
```

Comment: Just to understand, why do you feel it could be "better and cleaner"?  Did someone tell you that, or are you basing this off other code you have written?

Comment: @JohnPete22 Hi! I don't like repetitions this code has. I want my code to be DRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would curry `createStackNavigator`, and use `R.applySpec` to create a `stack` function, and `R.useWith` to generate a `createNavigator` function. Now you just need to pass the configs to get the `Navigator`.

Code sample (not tested):

```
const curriedCreateStackNavigator = R.curry(createStackNavigator)

const stacks = R.applySpec({
  SignUp: curriedCreateStackNavigator({ /* */ }),
  SignIn: curriedCreateStackNavigator({ /* */ }),
  App: curriedCreateStackNavigator({ /* */ }),
  Loading: R.always(Loading),
})

const createNavigator = R.useWith(R.compose(
  createAppContainer,
  createAnimatedSwitchNavigator
), [stacks, R.identity])

const switchNavigatorConfig = { /* */ }
const stackNavigatorConfig = { /* */ }

export default createNavigator(stackNavigatorConfig, switchNavigatorConfig)
```

Comment: Hi! It says "Cannot call a class as a function". Awesome sorcery btw

Comment: React is getting a class instead of a function. However, I can't really trace the error without more code. Can you create a minimal working example of your code (React instead of React Native)?